# Как увеличить изображение по пиксельно в react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, png, qrcode, expo

есть картинка png формата маленькая 30 на 30 пикселей надо увеличить картинку по пиксельно до 300 на 300 без потери качества может больше.
как это сделать?

Comment: а почему бы не приложить саму картинку

Comment: Без потери качества никак не получится. Вторая картинка содержит в 100 раз больше информации - откуда её взять?

Comment: @MBo я предположил что под потерей качества автор имеет в виду сглаживание при upsampling встроенным алгоритмом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать:

```js
let img = new Image(), from = 30, to = 300, ratio = to/from;
img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/1/${30}/${30}`;
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.onload = e => {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  let d1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, from, from);
  let d2 = ctx.createImageData(to, to);
  for (let x = 0; x<to; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y<to; y++) {
      let o1 = (y*to + x)*4;
      let o2 = (Math.floor(y/ratio)*from + Math.floor(x/ratio))*4;    
      d2.data[o1 + 0] = d1.data[o2 + 0];
      d2.data[o1 + 1] = d1.data[o2 + 1];
      d2.data[o1 + 2] = d1.data[o2 + 2];
      d2.data[o1 + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(d2, 0, 0); 
};
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=300 />
```

Comment: это react-native, не web

Comment: @Mike https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-canvas

Comment: @Mike в любом случае формула не поменяется

Comment: может быть, но там какие-то косяки с андроидом https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas/issues/138

Comment: под капотом react-native-webview?

Comment: @Mike чесслово не скажу, в целом это не важно, на любом апи надо просто делать тоже самое, хоть на opengl, хоть как, просто взять значения для каждого пикселя по формуле из ответа

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри еще эту ссылку, там по поводу масштабирования изображения:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#style

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} style={{ width: 300, height: 300, resizeMode: 'cover' }}/>
```

Comment: не получится эта картинка qrcode размытие убивает картинку в хлам

Answer (score 0):

Использовать OpenGL, и настроить итоговое изображение шейдерами

Готовый компонент:

- https://github.com/gre/gl-react-contrast-saturation-brightness

Шейдер + базовый компонент:

- https://github.com/gre/gl-react-native-v2
- https://github.com/rsn8887/Sharp-Bilinear-Shaders